# Python sqlalchemy connection fails with "socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a local postgres database connection through sqlalchemy. It manages to get inside the `with` statement, but then starts crashing as soon as I try to do anything with the connection.

```py
async with database.async_session.begin() as db_session:
    account = await AccountOrm.one_or_none(db_session, ...) # crash here, deep inside sqlalchemy internals
```

The very long stack trace goes down through sqlalchemy into the connection pool, ending with `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`. All other SO answers related to this error are about HTTP issues, so I'm at a bit of a loss at what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to someone's answer on one of the HTTP related questions, I realized that my database connection string was being built incorrectly.

I dynamically construct it from environment variable values, and my host name was unexpectedly empty when formatted into my database connection string, which explains the socket connection issue.

So triple check your connection string (or other connection info) if you're having this issue in relation to your database.